# how to add Hours and Minutes in to the total min which is contain in vector in java

Tags: java, time, type-conversion, min, hour

I have a Vectors which is containing Hours into this float type 00.00 so how to convert it into the HH.MM type and how to get Sum of all Elements of of that vector Can i have suggestion.

Comment: please tell us a bit about this.  10.10 == 10 hours and 10 minutes?  1.59 == one hour and 59 minutes? 1.75 == invalid?

Comment: nope its not valid bro..

Comment: what do you mean,  What is not valid.  Give more information.

Comment: 0.60 min it should be add as one hour cant u get it u dont know about timeline??

Comment: ah well, it does not matter in my answer.  It just works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    float ti = 2.56f;   // equals 2 hours and 56 minutes

    int hr = (int)(ti * 100) / 100;
    int min = (int)(ti * 100) % 100;
    System.out.println(hr);
    System.out.println(min);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hr);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

**Update**

If you have a collection of this objects, then you can iterate through them and add up to minutes.  You can also add up the hours.  Then ....

If you have 156 minutes,

```
int minutes = 156;
int hours = minutes  / 60;
min = minutes % 60;
```

you can these hours to your previous summed hours, and there you have it, total hours and minutes.

Comment: Well let me try this and ya btw if i add min that how it would be possible that i can add hours and min together.

Comment: Well that is right dude but i am having string so i have to parse double from that. then that will be continue is it?